# Rewrite rule for the following

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have news items on my website that get rewritten using the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /local/?page=home&news_id=$1&newsTitle=$2 [L]
```

Now one of the news item’s title is: `achieves_100%_A*_to_C_in_GCSE`

But the page doesn't get displayed and I get a 400 error.

I think that the problem is with the `%` and the `*` in the address.

How do I include both `%` and `*` in a reg exp.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: More of a serverfault question: my guess is that your user isn't applying URL encoding to `%` and `*` when requesting your URL. Try replacing with the correct URL encoding of these values and see if you still get the 400 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lone `%` is not valid in a URL. Replace it with `%25` when entering it in the address bar.